# NoMethodError:undefined method `symbolize_keys' in rspec test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rspec2

Here is the error for update in rspec:

```
  4) CustomersController GET customer page 'update' should be successful
     Failure/Error: post 'update', customer
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `symbolize_keys' for "1":String
     # ./spec/controllers/customers_controller_spec.rb:38:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

The rspec code:

```
it "'update' should be successful" do

  customer = Factory(:customer)      
  post 'update', customer
  response.should be_success
end
```

The update in customers controller:

```
  def update
    @customer = Customer.find(params[:id])
    if @customer.update_attributes(params[:customer], :as => :roles_new_update)
      if @customer.changed
        @message = 'The following info have been changed\n' + @customer.changes.to_s
        @subject ='Customer info was changed BY' + session[:user_name]
        notify_all_in_sales_eng(@message,@subject)
      end  

      redirect_to session[('page'+session[:page_step].to_s).to_sym], :notice => 'Customer was updated successfaully!'
    else
      render 'edit', :notice => 'Customer was not updated!'
    end
  end
```

Any thoughts about the error? Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I will not enter into details on RSpec, but I just met the same error and this is how I would correct it for your code:

```
it "'update' should be successful" do
  customer = Factory(:customer)      
  post 'update', :id => customer.id
  response.should be_success
end
```

I think you can't provide your object directly to the `post` method, you must pass it's `id` as in a `Hash` instead.

(Please note too that this code assumes your customer exists in the test database, so your Factory must `create` it.)

Comment: Probably want to add the posted customer params too, e.g. `post 'update', :id => customer.id, :customer => {:some_attribute => "some_value"}`

Comment: I can confirm that the reason is that the second argument to the `post` method must be a hash.